# D3 zoomable circle packing using flare.csv (not flare.json)

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to modify Mike Bostok's zoomable circle packing https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535
so that it uses a CSV file instead of a json file;a s for the non-zoomable version:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca5b03a33affa4160321

The data is being returned from a high speed database (SAP HANA). Returning formatted json is considerably more complex than returning a format that mimic's CSV so I'm merging the D3 examples for D3 Packed Circles (which uses CSV format data) with the D3 Zoomable Packed Circle (which uses json format data). And there my problems begin. I am new to D3.

I am unable to merge the two versions to get the zoom() and zoomTo() functions to work correctly - after calling zoomTo(). This is related to the definition of root or node - but I'm unable to figure out how what definition of "node" zoomTo() expects

The jsfiddle for the attempted merge is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/LbLpcjr4/17/

I commented out the zoomTo() - uncomment this line to see the problem I'm trying to fix:

```
//zoomTo(nodecircles,[root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);
```

Thsi displays the number of news articles for multinational companies for 2017, grouped by country, using data from GDELT.

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: anyone? I'm unable to find the right way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

so far i managed to fix the zoom but i broke the centering :

with a dirty

```
svg.select("g").attr("transform","translate("+(width/2)+","+(height/2)+")")
```

line 114 it "fix" it

https://jsfiddle.net/LbLpcjr4/39/
i declared `nodecircles` and `circle`   and changed the `zoomTo` to:

```
  function zoomTo(v) {
            nodecircles   =  svg.select("g").selectAll("g")
            circle   = svg.selectAll("circle");
            var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
            nodecircles.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
            circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience about this.
I leave you my project code (execute in xampp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.node--hover circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.2px;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
/*   stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px; */
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: #fff;
}

.label {
  font: 12px "Maison Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
/*   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff; */
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="960"><g transform="translate(1,1)"></g></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    margin = 1,
    diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var format = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([-1, 10])
    .range(["rgb(200,80,77)", "rgb(245,255,255)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([width - margin, height - margin])
    .padding(1);

d3.csv("./Visualise.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = stratify(data)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var focus = root,
      nodes = pack(root).descendants(),
      view;

  var circle = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { 
        return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; 
        })
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
            if(d.data.value == 0){
                return color(d.depth-1);
            }
            return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null; 
        })
      .on("click", function(d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { 
        if(d.data.value == 0){return 0;}
        return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
      .style("display", function(d) {
        if( d.data.value == 0 || d.data.value == "" ) {return "none";} 
        return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
      .text(function(d) { 
        if(d.data.value == 0){return;};

        return d.data.id.split(".").pop(-1) + "\n:\n"+ format(d.data.value); });//////

  var node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg
      .style("background", color(-1))
      .on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);

  function zoom(d) {
    var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

    var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
        .tween("zoom", function(d) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + margin]);
          return function(t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
        });

    transition.selectAll("text")
      .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
        .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
        .on("end", function(d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
  }

  function zoomTo(v) {
    var k = diameter / v[2]; view = v;
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) { return d.r * k; });
  }
});


</script>
//////visualise.csv
level,CategoryID,CategoryParentID,value,CategoryCount,id
0,-1,0,10000000,1000000,Cat
1,1,-1,263752,173805,Cat.egory_1
2,12,20081,0,0,Cat.egory_29.Leaf_1
3,13,50693,2470,337,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
4,14,13,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_2.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
5,18,2735,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_2.Leaf_1.Leaf_11.Leaf_1
5,22,2705,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_2.Leaf_1.Leaf_8.Leaf_1
5,23,1020,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_2.Leaf_1.Leaf_5.Leaf_1
3,24,18875,3017,440,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
4,25,24,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
4,26,24,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_2
3,27,18875,1173,227,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_2
3,28,1430,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_21.Leaf_1
3,30,717,0,0,Cat.egory_3.Leaf_5.Leaf_1
3,31,386,5,5,Cat.egory_4.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
4,32,326,0,0,Cat.egory_4.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
3,33,940,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_16.Leaf_1
2,34,1,3527,811,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1
4,35,13623,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_13.Leaf_1
3,36,34,616,84,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
5,37,35692,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_16.Leaf_1
5,38,13600,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_13.Leaf_1
3,39,34,677,221,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_2
4,40,39,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
5,41,156204,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
6,42,35672,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_2.Leaf_20.Leaf_1
3,44,593,64,64,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_11.Leaf_1
4,48,14281,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_35.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
2,51,64482,2797,323,Cat.egory_33.Leaf_1
3,52,51,0,0,Cat.egory_33.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
4,53,27259,0,0,Cat.egory_33.Leaf_1.Leaf_10.Leaf_1
3,56,51,0,0,Cat.egory_33.Leaf_1.Leaf_2
2,57,45100,388,132,Cat.egory_31.Leaf_1
3,58,57,0,0,Cat.egory_31.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
4,59,32987,0,0,Cat.egory_31.Leaf_1.Leaf_5.Leaf_1
3,60,57,1,1,Cat.egory_31.Leaf_1.Leaf_2
5,61,108726,0,0,Cat.egory_31.Leaf_1.Leaf_4.Leaf_8.Leaf_1
2,63,1,15791,5506,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2
3,64,63,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
3,65,63,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_2
3,66,63,175,52,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3
4,67,66,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3.Leaf_1
4,68,66,78,78,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3.Leaf_2
4,69,66,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3.Leaf_3
4,70,66,34,34,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3.Leaf_4
4,71,66,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3.Leaf_5
3,73,63,2002,144,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_4
4,74,73,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_4.Leaf_1
5,75,32723,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_4.Leaf_8.Leaf_1
4,76,73,1,1,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_4.Leaf_2
4,77,900,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_7.Leaf_1
3,79,63,6,6,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_5
3,80,63,447,447,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_6
3,81,13905,2115,145,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_32.Leaf_1
4,82,81,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_32.Leaf_1.Leaf_1
6,83,38140,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_32.Leaf_1.Leaf_4.Leaf_3.Leaf_1
5,84,4049,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_32.Leaf_1.Leaf_5.Leaf_1
4,86,27,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_1
4,87,24,34,34,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_3
4,88,24,0,0,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_4
4,89,27,64,64,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_2
4,90,27,21,21,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_3
4,91,24,1,1,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_5
4,92,24,139,139,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_6
4,93,24,12,12,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_7
4,95,24,10,10,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_1.Leaf_8
4,96,27,155,155,Cat.egory_13.Leaf_1.Leaf_2.Leaf_4
5,97,13779,0,0,Cat.egory_1.Leaf_29.Leaf_37.Leaf_29.Leaf_1
```